# Como pegar toDataURL para salvar em uma sessionStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, canvas

Estou utilizando uma biblioteca que peguei aqui neste link: https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper

Só que já passei 2 dias testando e procurando como pegar a imagem cortada com toDataURL para pegar a base64 e salvar ela em uma sessionStorage para eu utilizar depois..

Se alguém poder me dar uma mão...Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar dessa forma:

```
var canvas = $(img_selector).cropper('getCroppedCanvas'); //pega o canvas
var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'); //gera a base64 com o mimetype
var base64 = data.split(',').reverse()[0]; //pega somente o código
sessionStorage.setItem("base64", base64); //salva na storage
```

Você pode chamar esse pedaço de código em alguns momentos específicos:

Quando terminar o crop:

```
$(img_selector).on('cropend.cropper', function (e) {
    var $cropper = $(e.target);
    var canvas = $cropper.cropper('getCroppedCanvas');
    [...]
    // cole o resto do código aqui
});
```

Quando a cropbox está mudando:

```
$(img_selector).on('cropmove.cropper', function (e) {
    var $cropper = $(e.target);
    var canvas = $cropper.cropper('getCroppedCanvas');
    [...]
    // cole o resto do código aqui
});
```

Outros eventos do plugin podem ser achados [aqui](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper#events).

Comment: Mais não faço ideia onde adicionar este trecho...

Comment: Quando você quer fazer isso?

Comment: Quando for para cortar a imagem

Comment: Confere a edição.

Comment: Coloquei assim:

Comment: 'cropend.cropper': function (e) {
  var canvas = $().cropper('getCroppedCanvas'); //pega o canvas
  var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'); //gera a base64 com o mimetype
  var base64 = data.split(',').reverse()[0]; //pega somente o código
  alert(base64); //mostra na storage
    }

Comment: mais no google chrome mostra erro Uncaught TypeError: canvas.toDataURL is not a function

Comment: Galera Já resolvi o problema.. kkkk
O Problema era que o chrome não aceita executar isso ai em local...

Comment: para deixar claro, coloquei mais detalhado os códigos dentro dos eventos.